# subversion changing structure inside repository

Tags: svn

I am trying to change the structure of my repository and keep all history.

Currently it looks like this:

> http://svn-serv.address/new_repo/trunks/int/trunk/pc/shift

I would like to have that shift here:

> http://svn-serv.address/new_repo/trunks/int/shift

It looks like this because previously I made a dump of project from different repository to get only that shift and put it to new repo:

> svnadmin dump dif_repo | svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs include trunk/pc/shift > dumpfile.out

next I've created missing folders and loaded that dump:

> sudo -u wwwrun svnadmin load --parent-dir trunks/init new_repo < dumpfile.out

I would like to change that path now but I don't know how to do that.

My svn version: 1.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the folder `shift` inside `http://svn-serv.address/new_repo/trunks/int/`. Further you can delete the `trunk` folder inside `http://svn-serv.address/new_repo/trunks/int/` if not required. svn move will not delete any history. In tortoise svn you can just drag and drop and can achieve this.

`svn help rename` Please check this.